# Grid Adding Row with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have Grid View and Following Code In javascript to add new row. Problem is that when i click button to add new row it adds row but It contain the previous row data also and don't saves to DB. It generates error "Invalid Number".

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
        function AddNewRecord()
        {
            var grd = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            var tbod=grd.rows[0].parentNode;
            var newRow=grd.rows[grd.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
            tbod.appendChild(newRow);
            return false;

        }
    </script>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add Row" OnClientClick="return AddNewRecord();"/>
```

What should i do so that row should generate empty and also should saves to DB.

I have this code for Grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" OnRowCreated="myGridView_ItemCreated"  Headerstyle-CssClass="myStyle"
                                BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Width="859px">
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Card No">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardNo" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zone">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlZone" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                                                DataTextField="ZONE_DESC" DataValueField="ZONE_NO" Width="80px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand='SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "MLK_00_05" order by Zone_DESC'>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle No">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVeh" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="VEHICLE_NUMBER"
                                                DataValueField="VEH_COD" Width="80px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand='SELECT DISTINCT VEHICLE_NUMBER, DEVICEID, VEH_COD FROM MLK_VEHICLE ORDER BY 1'>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartDate" runat="server" Width="80px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>


                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HH  MM">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartHH" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMM" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="800px" Wrap="False" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            HH &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; MM
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntryDate" runat="server" Width="80px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hh:mm">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntryHH" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntryMM" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            HH &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; MM
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrossDate" runat="server" Width="80px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hh:mm">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrossHH" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrossMM" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            HH &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; MM
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gross Weight(kg)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossWt" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tare Weight(kg)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTareWt" runat="server" Width="60px" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Weight(kg)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNetWt" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            &nbsp;
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlTareDate" runat="server" Width="80px" >
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hh:mm">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTareHH" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTareMM" runat="server" Width="50px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            HH &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; MM
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FAT(%)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFat" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LR">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLR" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNF(%)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSNF" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Protein(%)">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProtein" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MBRT">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMBRT" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cheese">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheese" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distance">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDistance" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="CornflowerBlue" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" CssClass="myStyle" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Any One can Give answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are doing `cloneNode(true)` , it will just clone the previous row and hence have the same data as previous row. to make it empty use the `.text("")` with each element in row, since you have not included the html i cant write the code.

Comment: Do U Mean HTML of Gridview or Button on which function is being called

Comment: can you please paste your one complete row element?

Comment: Yes I have now paste the Whole code I f u say i can paste my vb.net code for Inserting and loading Gridview

Comment: So what i have to do For adding a new row with empty texboxes and able to inserted in DB

Answer (score 0):

For you scenario, You create a new row in gridview by javasscript, but the new row is not a server side control, So when do postback, The state of control can't save in viewstate,This is the reason why you can't save to DB.

So i think you can add a asp:hidden field in page , combine the data of new row(all columns) and store in it,when you click a button,It should trigger a postback event, you can get the data of new row by the value of this hidden field. and then save them to DB.